# Fastest or most idiomatic way to remove object from list of objects in Python

Tags: python, performance, list

Suppose I have a list `L` of **unknown** objects, `O1` to `On`, and I want to remove another object reference `M` which *may* refer to one of the objects in `L`, I've managed to do it using:

```
L = [ O1, O2, ... On]

...

L = [ j for j in L if j not in [ M ] ]
```

which is lovely and idiomatic... but I'm having to do it a lot, and I wonder if there's not another more idiomatic way, or if there is not a faster way.

The important point is that the list of objects is **unknown**, and *may* or *may not* include the object to be excluded. I want to avoid extending or subclassing the objects where possible.

Comment: List comprehension will be the fastest way (list comprehensions are generally faster in Python + it will be with O(n) complexity). On a side note, if `M` is a single object why would you want to do `j not in [M]`? `j == M` will definitely be a little faster as direct comparisons are always faster.

Comment: `try:L.remove(M) except ValueError:pass`? However the `remove` method only removes the first element equal to `M`.

Comment: can there be more than one instance of M in the list?

Comment: The problem here is that if your objects are unknown, you don't know whether they are hashable. This is why you can't use a set and end up with quadratic runtime. In practice, having a list of objects with completely unknown properties seems weird. Where and why are you getting this list? To me this looks like a problem upstream, which needs to be fixed upstream if you want to avoid quadratic runtime for the filtering.

Comment: I agree @timgeb - but sadly, I'm just they guy downstream from the sewage-works...

Comment: In place changes are probably better in this case, I suspect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.remove` seems to be the fastest way, with list comprehension as the second fastest and `filter` at last.

Here are the `timeit` results

```
In: python -m timeit '[x for x in [1,2,3,4,5] if x not in [4]]'
Out: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.285 usec per loop

In: python -m timeit '[x for x in [1,2,3,4,5] if x != 4]'
Out: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.254 usec per loop

In: python -m timeit 'filter(lambda x: x not in [4], [1,2,3,4,5])'
Out: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.577 usec per loop

In: python -m timeit 'filter(lambda x: x != 4, [1,2,3,4,5])'
Out: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.569 usec per loop

In: python -m timeit '[1,2,3,4,5].remove(4)'
Out: 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.132 usec per loop
```

Comment: Your results for remove are too optimistic, because you should add a `try except` to catch a possible `ValueError`. But I agree with you it's still the best way - provided OP want to change the original list because other methods builds a copy..

Comment: Agreed about the Try. Thanks @Muhammad

Comment: @SergeBallesta you are right, in case of `try except + no exception` it was still faster than list comprehension but for `try except + raised exception` it was slower than list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

What about the built in [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function?

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> f = [4]
>>> filter(lambda x: x not in f, l)
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

or in python3

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x not in f, l))
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Note: this does **not** return a `list` in python3+.

Comment: added the python3 version

Answer (score 2):

Use `try`/`except` wrapped in a recursive function
recursion takes care of potential multiple `M`'s

```
def tremove(L, M):
    try:
        L.remove(M)
        return tremove(L, M)
    except:
        return L

tremove(L, M)
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are multiple occurences of your value then probably a `while`-loop with `remove` is needed:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5]
while True:
    try:
        L.remove(4)
    except:
        break
```

It is a bit slower (due to the exception handling and multiple iterations over the list) than the list comprehension:

```
[ j for j in L if j != 4 ]
```

but both do work fine. If you want to exclude multiple values then you should use the list-comprehension:

```
M = [1, 4]
[ j for j in L if j not in M ]
```

because the `try` / `except` will be nested and the list comprehension only needs to traverse the list once.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea that let's you make O(1) containment checks for hashable items. It should be dramatically faster for long lists `M` with lots of hashables.

```
class MixedBag(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.hashed = set()
        self.nothashed = []

        for x in args:
            self.add(x)

    def add(self, x):
        try:
            self.hashed.add(x)
        except TypeError:
            self.nothashed.append(x)

    def __contains__(self, x):
        try:
            return x in self.hashed
        except TypeError:
            return x in self.nothashed


L = [[1,2,3], 4, '5', {6}]
M = [[1,2,3], '5', {4}]

mix = MixedBag(*M)
L = [x for x in L if x not in mix]
print(L) # [4, set([6])]
```